# How can I modify Arduino code to work with ATtiny85?

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny85

[image: Circuit designed to work with ATtiny85]Push a tactile switch to cycle through several different patterns on the LED strips. I want to modify the Arduino code so that I can use the ATtiny85 instead. 
*****The code posted here works on the Arduino Uno with a 10k pull-up resistor wired to the push button at pin 11 on the Arduino.

```cpp
/***************************************************************************/
//            Hardware: RadioShack Tricolor LED Strip
//            Arduino IDE: Arduino-1.0
//            Date:      April 17, 2013
//            Copyright© 2013 RadioShack Corporation
//
//  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
//  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
//  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
//  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
//
//  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
//  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
//  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
//  Lesser General Public License for more details.
//
//  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
//  License along with this library; if not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>
//
/*****************************************************************************/

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

// ******** DEBUG ==== should auto config to adapt different mother board *********
#define DATA_1 (PORTC |=  0X01)    // DATA 1    // for UNO
#define DATA_0 (PORTC &=  0XFE)    // DATA 0    // for UNO
#define STRIP_PINOUT (DDRC=0xFF)    // for UNO

int val = 0; //variable to read button pin value
int buttonPin = 11; //button pin variable, 11 on the Arduino
int sequence = 1; //variable to hold current sequence

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_blue_comet_red_bg[][20] = {
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},

};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_disco[][20] = {
  {0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011},
  {0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022},
  {0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033},
  {0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044},
  {0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055},
  {0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066},
  {0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077},
  {0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088},
  {0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099},
  {0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa},
  {0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb},
  {0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc},
  {0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd},
  {0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000},
  {0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000},
  {0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000},
  {0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000},
  {0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000},
  {0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000},
  {0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000},
  {0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000},
  {0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000},
  {0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000},
  {0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000},
  {0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000},
  {0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000},
  {0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000},
  {0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000},
  {0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100},
  {0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200},
  {0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300},
  {0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400},
  {0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500},
  {0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600},
  {0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700},
  {0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800},
  {0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900},
  {0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00},
  {0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00},
  {0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00},
  {0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00},
  {0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00},
  {0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_pink[][20] = {
  {0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_purple[][20] = {
  {0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_blue[][20] = {
  {0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_green[][20] = {
  {0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_yellow[][20] = {
  {0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_white[][20] = {
  {0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_red[][20] = {
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
};

// ***********************************************************************************************************
// *
// *                            Power Up Init.
// *
// *
// ***********************************************************************************************************
void setup() {

  STRIP_PINOUT;        // set output pin - DEBUG: should auto detect which mother board for use

  reset_strip();
  //noInterrupts();

}



// ***********************************************************************************************************
// *
// *                            Main Loop
// *
// *
// ***********************************************************************************************************
void loop()
{

  val = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (val == LOW)
  {
    if (sequence == 9)
    {
      sequence = 1;
    } else
    {
      sequence++;
    }
    delay(200);
  }

  switch (sequence)
  {
    case 1:
      send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_pink, 1, 5);
      delay(1);
      break;
    case 2:
      send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_purple, 1, 5);
      delay(1);
      break;
    case 3:
      send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_blue, 1, 5);
      delay(1);
      break;
    case 4:
      send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_green, 1, 5);
      delay(1);
      break;
    case 5:
      send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_yellow, 1, 5);
      delay(1);
      break;
    case 6:
      send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_white, 1, 5);
      delay(1);
      break;
    case 7:
      send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_red, 1, 5);
      delay(1);
      break;
    case 8:
      send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_blue_comet_red_bg, 43, 45);
      delay(1);
      break;
    case 9:
      send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_disco, 45, 5);
      delay(1);
      break;
  }

  //delay(1);
}


/*******************************************************************************
   Function Name  : send_1M_pattern
   Description    : Transmit pattern to whole 1 meter strip
   Input          : pointer to ROM pattern; pattern length; frame rate
   Output         : None
   Return         : None
 *******************************************************************************/
void send_1M_pattern(const unsigned long data[][20], int pattern_no, int frame_rate)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  uint32_t temp_data;

  for (i = 0; i < pattern_no; i++)
  {
    noInterrupts();
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
      temp_data = pgm_read_dword_near(&data[i][j]);
      send_strip(temp_data);
    }
    interrupts();

    delay(frame_rate);

  }
}

/*******************************************************************************
   Function Name  : send_strip
   Description    : Transmit 24 pulse to LED strip
   Input          : 24-bit data for the strip
   Output         : None
   Return         : None
 *******************************************************************************/
void send_strip(uint32_t data)
{
  int i;
  unsigned long j = 0x800000;


  for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
  {
    if (data & j)
    {
      DATA_1;
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");

      /*----------------------------*/
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      /*----------------------------*/
      DATA_0;
    }
    else
    {
      DATA_1;
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      DATA_0;
      /*----------------------------*/
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      /*----------------------------*/
    }

    j >>= 1;
  }
}

/*******************************************************************************
   Function Name  : reset_strip
   Description    : Send reset pulse to reset all color of the strip
   Input          : None
   Output         : None
   Return         : None
 *******************************************************************************/
void  reset_strip()
{
  DATA_0;
  delayMicroseconds(20);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70216/discussion-on-question-by-camden-crowley-how-can-i-modify-arduino-code-to-work-w).

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the lines

```
#define DATA_1 (PORTC |=  0X01)    // DATA 1    // for UNO
#define DATA_0 (PORTC &=  0XFE)    // DATA 0    // for UNO
#define STRIP_PINOUT (DDRC=0xFF)    // for UNO
int buttonPin = 11; //button pin variable, 11 on the Arduino
```

with

```
#define DATA_1 (PORTB |=  0X01)    // DATA 1    // on PB0
#define DATA_0 (PORTB &=  0XFE)    // DATA 0    // on PB0
#define STRIP_PINOUT (DDRB=0x01)    // PB0 as output
int buttonPin = 3; //button pin variable, pin 3 = PB3
```

Connect the push button between PB3 and GND, with an external pullup.
Connect PB0 to the data input of the LED strip.

If the program doesn't fit in the flash, try removing one of the largest
patterns. Otherwise, if it almost fits, you could try to optimize it to
make it smaller.

---

**Edit**: I modified the original code and added some optimizations.
Notably, I removed all dependencies to the Arduino core, which makes it
significantly smaller. Now it fits in the flash memory of the ATtiny85
without removing any pattern.

This is a polyglot: it should compile either as a .ino sketch, as a
plain C program, or as a C++ program.

Here is the code:

```
/***************************************************************************/
//            Hardware: RadioShack Tricolor LED Strip
//            Arduino IDE: Arduino-1.0
//            Date:      April 17, 2013
//            Copyright© 2013 RadioShack Corporation
//
//  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
//  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
//  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
//  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
//
//  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
//  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
//  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
//  Lesser General Public License for more details.
//
//  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
//  License along with this library; if not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>
//
/*****************************************************************************/
// Modified to work on an ATtiny85 by Edgar Bonet -- 2017-12-12.
//
// Wiring:
//   - connect a push button between PB3 and GND
//   - connect PB0 to the data input of the LED strip
//
// Compile:
//   avr-gcc -mmcu=attiny85 -Os -Wall -Wextra -DF_CPU=8000000
//   Tricolor-LED-Strip.c -o Tricolor-LED-Strip.elf
/*****************************************************************************/

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

// Change this if you want to use different pins.
#define DATA_PIN   PB0
#define BUTTON_PIN PB3

void send_1M_pattern(const unsigned long data[][20], uint8_t pattern_no, uint8_t frame_rate);
void send_strip(uint32_t data);
void reset_strip();

static void short_delay(uint8_t ms)
{
  while (ms--) _delay_ms(1);
}

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_blue_comet_red_bg[][20] = {
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100, 0x00ff00},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x001100},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x00ff00, 0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x001100, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},

};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_disco[][20] = {
  {0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011, 0x000011},
  {0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022, 0x000022},
  {0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033, 0x000033},
  {0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044, 0x000044},
  {0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055, 0x000055},
  {0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066, 0x000066},
  {0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077, 0x000077},
  {0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088, 0x000088},
  {0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099, 0x000099},
  {0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa, 0x0000aa},
  {0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb, 0x0000bb},
  {0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc, 0x0000cc},
  {0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd, 0x0000dd},
  {0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee, 0x0000ee},
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
  {0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000, 0x110000},
  {0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000, 0x220000},
  {0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000, 0x330000},
  {0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000, 0x440000},
  {0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000, 0x550000},
  {0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000, 0x660000},
  {0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000, 0x770000},
  {0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000, 0x880000},
  {0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000, 0x990000},
  {0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000, 0xaa0000},
  {0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000, 0xbb0000},
  {0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000, 0xcc0000},
  {0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000, 0xdd0000},
  {0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000, 0xee0000},
  {0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000},
  {0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100, 0x001100},
  {0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200, 0x002200},
  {0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300, 0x003300},
  {0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400, 0x004400},
  {0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500, 0x005500},
  {0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600, 0x006600},
  {0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700, 0x007700},
  {0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800, 0x008800},
  {0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900, 0x009900},
  {0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00, 0x00aa00},
  {0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00, 0x00bb00},
  {0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00, 0x00cc00},
  {0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00, 0x00dd00},
  {0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00, 0x00ee00},
  {0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_pink[][20] = {
  {0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff, 0x00ffff},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_purple[][20] = {
  {0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66, 0x00cc66},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_blue[][20] = {
  {0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff00},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_green[][20] = {
  {0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xff0000},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_yellow[][20] = {
  {0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00ff},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_white[][20] = {
  {0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffff},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_red[][20] = {
  {0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff},
};

static const struct {
  const unsigned long (*data)[20];
  uint8_t pattern_no;
  uint8_t frame_rate;
} patterns[9] = {
  {pattern_test_pink, 1, 5},
  {pattern_test_purple, 1, 5},
  {pattern_test_blue, 1, 5},
  {pattern_test_green, 1, 5},
  {pattern_test_yellow, 1, 5},
  {pattern_test_white, 1, 5},
  {pattern_test_red, 1, 5},
  {pattern_test_blue_comet_red_bg, 43, 45},
  {pattern_test_disco, 45, 5}
};


// ***********************************************************************************************************
// *
// *                            Main Program
// *
// *
// ***********************************************************************************************************
int main(void)
{
  uint8_t sequence = 0; //variable to hold current sequence

  DDRB |= _BV(DATA_PIN);     // DATA_PIN as output
  PORTB |= _BV(BUTTON_PIN);  // internal pullup on button pin
  reset_strip();

  for (;;) {
    if ((PINB & _BV(BUTTON_PIN)) == 0) {  // if the button is pressed
      if (++sequence == 9)
        sequence = 0;
      short_delay(200);
    }
    send_1M_pattern(
      patterns[sequence].data,
      patterns[sequence].pattern_no,
      patterns[sequence].frame_rate
    );
    short_delay(1);
  }
}


/*******************************************************************************
   Function Name  : send_1M_pattern
   Description    : Transmit pattern to whole 1 meter strip
   Input          : pointer to ROM pattern; pattern length; frame rate
   Output         : None
   Return         : None
 *******************************************************************************/
void send_1M_pattern(const unsigned long data[][20], uint8_t pattern_no, uint8_t frame_rate)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  uint32_t temp_data;

  for (i = 0; i < pattern_no; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
      temp_data = pgm_read_dword_near(&data[i][j]);
      send_strip(temp_data);
    }

    short_delay(frame_rate);

  }
}

/*******************************************************************************
   Function Name  : send_strip
   Description    : Transmit 24 pulse to LED strip
   Input          : 24-bit data for the strip
   Output         : None
   Return         : None
 *******************************************************************************/
void send_strip(uint32_t data)
{
  int i;
  unsigned long j = 0x800000;


  for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
  {
    if (data & j)
    {
      PORTB |= _BV(DATA_PIN);
      _delay_us(1.75);
      PORTB &= ~_BV(DATA_PIN);
    }
    else
    {
      PORTB |= _BV(DATA_PIN);
      _delay_us(0.563);
      PORTB &= ~_BV(DATA_PIN);
      _delay_us(0.188);
    }

    j >>= 1;
  }
}

/*******************************************************************************
   Function Name  : reset_strip
   Description    : Send reset pulse to reset all color of the strip
   Input          : None
   Output         : None
   Return         : None
 *******************************************************************************/
void  reset_strip()
{
  PORTB &= ~_BV(DATA_PIN);
  _delay_us(20);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70215/discussion-on-answer-by-edgar-bonet-how-can-i-modify-arduino-code-to-work-with-a).